# Disable JFace TableViwer single row

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

Does anyone know how to disable a single row of a JFace `TableViwer`? I have a `TableViwer` constructed as follows:

```java
TableViwer tv = new TableViwer(composite, SWT.NONE| SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
```

tv can have many rows, but I am adding a particular unique row to the table dynamically(when an external button is clicked) and I need to make only that row disabled (grayed out and not selectable. Not selectable can also be achieved through existing handler, if there is no other option).

I searched in google but did not get much information. I am new to SWT/JFace, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something in the selection listener to reject selection of the row.

To make the row gray you can make your Label Provider implement `IColorProvider` which lets you define the two methods:

```java
public Color getForeground(Object element);
public Color getBackground(Object element);
```

which can color the row.

You could also use a label provider derived from `StyledCellLabelProvider` which lets you define more complex coloring.

Comment: Hi @Greg......Thank you for your help, background color is getting set when i add the row. But now I am facing one more problem, actually user has option to save the data in xml. So when the table loads the data first time from the xml, background color does not getting changed.

Comment: That is a new question. Accept this answer and then ask a new question showing a minimal version of the problem code.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Greg, I have accepted your answer.